# Java Mono in Mono Response out of Order

Tags: java

I am new to Mono. I have migrated an existing non reactive RepsonseEntity API to use all Mono calls. There is one call that gets a Mono<List> and then needs to run a second Mono call for each Workflow in the list that will return a Workflow with the tasks included. It then needs to take the tasks and set them in the Workflow in the list. Optionally, it could just replace the entire workflow with the copy of the workflow in the second call that includes the tasks.

The issue is that I can not get the order properly with my lack of Mono knowledge. Logically my code works but it is returning the response to the requestor before the Workflow is replaced by the second Mono call. I believe I need to use then or zip maybe but I have not been able to get them entered correctly.

```
public Mono<List<Workflow>> getWorkflows_0(String name, String correlationId, Boolean includeClosed, Boolean includeTasks) {
    return extendedWorkflowApiR.getWorkflows_0(name, correlationId, includeClosed, includeTasks)
        .map(wfList -> {
            if (!wfList.isEmpty() && includeClosed){
                for (Workflow wf : wfList) {
                    if (wf.getTasks().isEmpty() && includeTasks) {
                        extendedWorkflowApiR.getExecutionStatus(wf.getWorkflowId(), includeTasks)
                            .map(wfWithTasks -> {
                                wf.setTasks(wfWithTasks.getTasks());
                                return Mono.just(wf);
                            });                        
                    }
                }   
            }
        return wfList;
    });
}
```

I have tried using map, flatmap, tried making the second mono a private method and calling it instead. I have tried many different versions with System.Outs and it always prints the final return before the getExecutionStatus mono returns and fixed the Workflow.

I need the first Mono to return the List of workflows. Then be able to run through the list with each one potentially calling a second mono and fixing the list. Then at the end return the completed list. I also seem to have to subscribe to the inner mono or it wont ever trigger that one. currently that subscribe is not in code sample.

Comment: Are you referring to this [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html)?

Comment: Yes I am referring that that Mono. I have tried many of the methods. map, flatmap. I think zip sounds like it might be the right path but I am not sure how to get the result of the first mono to be able to be used in the second mono in a loop. Or have not been able to use an iterable properly.